# Is it possible to run ksh/bash with an alternative profile?

Tags: shell

The situation: In my job I often have to `su` to other userIDs, which means I lose my settings from my `.profile` - to restore them, I have to manually source my profile.

Isn't there a way to automate this? If there was an option to specify an alternative login script, I could put it into an alias along the lines of:

```
alias myksh='sudo -u someuser ksh --alt-profile /path/to/my/profile'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alias myksh="sudo -u someuser HOME=$HOME ksh"
```

Also, ksh and bash (with `--posix`) look for a startup file in the expansion of `$ENV`

Comment: This looks promising. Alas, I've just found out that ksh isn't installed, and it isn't something that can be easily amended (since it would have to be done on some 700 servers)

Comment: But fortunately it works with HOME=$HOME bash --login

Comment: might work for bash if your startup is sufficiently vanilla

Comment: well, so far it is only aliases and maybe later shell functions